# Summernote WYSIWYG video issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, video

I am using summernote wysiwyg editor and it function OK, except the video module which works only in Mozilla Firefox, but not in Google Chrome and Opera (I haven't tested in Safari).

After I involve a video in a summernote textarea, than I want to submit/post the created summernote code for that video to a database using post.php file.

Below is the code and print screen of index.html and post.php

Thank you

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNHjr.png)

[post.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ44U.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Summernote</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="jquery-3.2.1/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script> 
  <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="summernote.css">
  <script src="summernote.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<form method="post" action="post.php">
  
<textarea id="summernote" name="textarea">Hello Summernote</textarea>

  <script>
    $('#summernote').summernote({
      height: 350,
      toolbar: [
        ['style', ['style']],
        ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'clear']],
        ['fontname', ['fontname']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
        ['height', ['height']],
        ['table', ['table']],
        ['insert', ['link', 'unlink', 'picture', 'video','hr']],
        ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
        ['help', ['help']]
      ],
    });
  </script>
  
  <input type="submit" />
  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Summernote</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php

  $textarea=$_POST['textarea'];
  
  echo $textarea;
  
  // ...Here will be the code for inserting the textarea  content (code) to a database like long text data type

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try it without inserting a video to the textarea? what happens if you just submit e.g. `foo`?

Comment: The problem that I asked solved when I upload summernote files to the xammp server, but I do know why it doesnt outside the serve. Thank you

Comment: `PHP` needs a server to run properly. If you just opened the html-file with a browser, it's clear that it could not work.

Comment: Thank you for your short and clean answer. If you want add your responce as an answer to mark it as the right one